# How to link to a wordpress blog from a static page in a single host computer?

Tags: html, wordpress, hosting

I have a introduction page that is totally html and a blog based on Wordpress. I aim to link my log from the Static page and vice a versa. Is it possible to host both of those pages ina single host by linking each other. If it is, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; if you're using Apache, you can set the html page to be served by default using .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

will ensure that the html file is read before Wordpress's index.php. In the html file you can add a simple link, and in WP you can add arbitrary URLs using custom menus, that will enable you to link back to the introduction page.